# How to plot a 2d Function in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, plot, octave, array-broadcasting

I am trying to plot a simple equation in MATLAB.

The equation is

```
z = x^2 - y^2, for -3 <= x <= 3, -3 <= y <= 3.
```

The current code that I have is

```
x = -3:3;
y = -3:3;
z = (x.^2) - (y.^2);
plot(z)
```

The result is

[image]

Please help me in this case because I am not sure if the code and graph is correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a piecewise function. A [Piecewise Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) is a function defined by multiple sub-functions, where each sub-function applies to a different interval in the domain. There is only one function here that takes two arrays of the same length. The calculations yield a vector of zeros, due to the input arrays. If you change either one of the vectors, that is "x" or "y", you will see a nonzero plot. Your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going wrong here: Let's start at the beginning:

```
x = -3:3;
y = -3:3;
```

If we evaluate these they both will return an vector of integers:

```
x =

-3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3
```

This means that the grid on which the function is evaluated is going to be very coarse. To alleviate this you can define a step size, e.g. `x = 3:0.1:3` or use [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), in which case you set the number of samples, so e.g. `x = linspace(-3, 3, 500)`. Now consider the next line:

```
z = (x.^2) - (y.^2);
```

If we evaluate this we get

```
z =
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and you plot this vector with the 2d-plotting function

```
plot(z)
```

which perfectly explains why you get a straight line. This is because the automatic broadcasting of the arithmetic operators like minuse (`-`) just subtracts values entry-wise. You however want to evaluate `z` for each possible pair of values of `x` and `y`. To do this and to get a nice plot later you should use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), and use a plotting function like [`mesh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) to plot it. So I'd recommend using

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

to create the grid and then evaluate the function on the grid as follows

```
Z = X.^2 - Y.^2;
```

and finally plot your function with

```
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```